# z-score equation variables

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, means, standard-deviation, data-analysis

I am comparing 2 variables and have an outlier in x of 82.27. I want to find the z score of this outlier. When using the z score equation x-mean/standard deviation, do I use the mean and standard deviation of my x values or y values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the observation of 82.27 belongs to the variable $x$, then we use the mean and standard deviation for $x$ to find the $z$-score: $$z=\frac{x-\mu_x}{\sigma_x}=\frac{82.27-\mu_x}{\sigma_x}$$

Comment: If my observation was part of the variable y would I just use the mean and stdv of y?

Comment: @Joe that's correct